# PrimeFaces number of files in FileUpload

Tags: jsf, upload, primefaces

I'm very new to PrimeFaces components. I have a FileUpload (multiple files uploaded) and I want to know if there's a way to know how many files are in the upload component **before** uploading them.
   What I need is to upload 1 to 6 files and just after the 6th is uploaded process the all the files.
   Any idea on how can I achieve this is very welcome.

Cheers

**UPDATE**
Already tried with `oncomplete` but it does not help me 'cause this event is executed every time a file is uploaded not 'till all files are.

Comment: I don't really understood a thing: do you want to be able to upload each of the 6 files, so actually upload them, and then call a processing method? Or do you want to actually start the upload only after all the 6 files are in the uploading state?

Comment: Upload them all and then call a processing method.

Comment: Seeing that this question was asked in 2011 and now its 2015, @BRabbit27, you might have got a lot of experience. Can you please tell me about this now? How can someone know how many files are uploaded?

Comment: @bugsHappen im sorrx i didnt keep on going on that ttack for my career. Decided to move to 3d graphics and numerical sims.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this is pretty old thread but I've found straitforward way to determine the number of files been uploaded.

`p:fileUpload` widget has an array with meta-info about selected files. By passing the length of this array to your bean you will obtain the total number of files.

There is a problem though: `p:fileUpload` doesn't submit the surrounding form, so I had to put invisible button along with the `h:inputHidden` to pass the number of files from JavaScript to ManagedBean:

```
<h:form id="importDlgForm">
    <p:fileUpload id="importFile" widgetVar="importFile" fileUploadListener="#{importDialogView.importFile}"
                      mode="advanced" multiple="true"
                      onstart="$('#importDlgForm\\:file_number_input').val(PF('importFile').files.length);
                      $('#importDlgForm\\:submit_btn').click();"/>
    <h:inputHidden id="file_number_input" value="#{importDialogView.importFileNumber}"/>
    <p:commandButton id="submit_btn" style="display: none"/>
</h:form>
```

I also had to use `AtomicInteger` in order to track processed files, as `p:fileUpload` uses multiple threads to upload files by default.

```
private final AtomicInteger atomicImportFileNumber = new AtomicInteger();
private Integer importFileNumber;

public Integer getImportFileNumber() {
    return importFileNumber;
}

public void setImportFileNumber(Integer importFileNumber) {
    this.importFileNumber = importFileNumber;
    atomicImportFileNumber.set(importFileNumber);
}

public void importFile(FileUploadEvent event) {
    // common file upload stuff
    if (atomicImportFileNumber.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
        // part to execute only when all files have been uploaded   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload all the files,  all 6 of them at once or only 1 at a time, and then call a processing message, you have to create a variable or better a `list` where you insert the name of each file, or even the file objects and when the ArrayList size reach 6 you call a processing method. Simple as that!

```
private ArrayList<UploadedFile> listWithUploadedFile = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();
public void uploadMethod(){
//upload file, save input stream and any other thing you want
  listWithUploadedFile.add(file);
  if(listWithUploadedFile.size==6){
    myProcessUploadedFilesMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that would do it, but the problem is how to make that dynamic, because the user sometimes will upload 6 files, sometimes 1 file, sometimes 3 files... I want to know how many files are going to be uploaded or even better I want to know when all files are uploaded. So when the user selects 3 files set a flag just when the 3rd file was uploaded completely

Comment: @BRabbit27 I thought you know exactly all the files the user is supposed to upload, if you don't know you can't use the attribute `sizeLimit` because you never know...the user might upload 4,5,6 files now and after a minute upload another files; there are two things you can do: implement a button named for example `done uploading files` and after the button is pressed you can call a processing method(ajax or non-ajax)   or   you can implement a javascript function (or use RequestContext object) that disables the upload tag (or even hide it) if after,let's say, 5 minutes, no file is uploaded

Comment: Yeah thanks! I think I'll put another button to indicate that upload is finished. I just wanted to know if there was a way to know how many files were uploaded. Is it possible to know when all files are uploaded? I mean something like `oncomplete` event but this fires for every file, is there an event for the whole upload (after all files were uploaded) ?

Comment: @BRabbit27 Think for a second, there's no way to know the upload is finished unless you, the programmer, make a convention!!! Because the user may upload now 3 files, after 1 minute another 6 files and after 5 minutes another 2 files! YOU are the one who can stop the upload by pressing a button or by setting a timer and after that timer runs out, the user can't upload anymore...

Comment: Well I'm not agree with that... To make this simple, the user uploads X number of files and I want to run a process after the Xth file was uploaded completely. I don't care if the user uploads 1 file now and two hours later 5 files. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the Aleksandr's answer to simplify the `onstart` command, by the price of more complicated Java part.

```
</div>
  <p:fileUpload widgetVar="importFile" listener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" dragDropSupport="true" mode="advanced" multiple="true"
                        onstart="rc([{name:'size', value:PF('importFile').files.length}])"/>
  <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="messages" actionListener="#{fileUploadView.setSize}" />
</div>
```

and

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class FileUploadView {

  private AtomicInteger size = new AtomicInteger();

  private List<UploadedFile> files = new ArrayList<>();

  public void setSize(ActionEvent e) {
    String length  = e.getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("size");
    if(length != null) {
      size.set(Integer.parseInt(length));
    }
  }
  public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    files.add(event.getFile());
    if(size.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
      FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Successful", files.size() + " uploaded");
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
      files.clear();
    }
  }
}
```